# How to take snapshot from RSTP link with python-vlc

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-vlc

I want to take a snapshot from a RSTP link without open the screen in Ubuntu 20.04, I've followed a few Stack Overflow users tips, but none of them worked.

Today I can display the RSTP link on a VLC window, but can't take snapshot.

As you can see in the code, I'm trying to use video_take_snapshot in many ways, but none of them saved the file anywhere. I tried to take the snapshot while the video was playing and in pause modes. also tried to save in default directory and specific directory. Also tried a lot of other solutions but none of them worked

ps: I tried openCV, which my company uses today, but we need to change because it have incompatibility issues with specific onvif RSTP cams

```
url = 'rtsp://labs:yBtYHJ35Hk@mediastreaming.grupoavantia.com.br/Operacional/avantia_frente_sede.stream'
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
Instance = vlc.Instance()
p = Instance.media_player_new()
p.set_mrl(url)
p.play()
                
# wait so the video can be played 
time.sleep(25)
                
print("######## SCRENSHOT1 ############ ")
media_player.video_take_snapshot(0, "foobar.png", 400, 300)
media_player.pause()

print("######## SCRENSHOT2 ############ ")
media_player.video_take_snapshot(0, "/home/mariocardoso/Pictures/tests/foobar2.png", 400, 300)
time.sleep(5)

print("######## SCRENSHOT3 ############ ")
media_player.video_take_snapshot(0, "//home//mariocardoso//Pictures//tests//foobar3.png", 0, 0)
time.sleep(10)
```

So, my solution needs 2 steps: make it possible to take a snapshot and make it without open the screen.

Comment: Why do you create a new instance? You shouldn't need that, but since that's the player that's playing the media, you need `p.video_take_snapshot`.

Comment: that's what i needed! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use ffmpeg for this case

for ex:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://@... -acodec copy -vcodec copy c:/abc.mp4
```

Comment: This solutions generates a .mp4 file that doesn't even open in ubuntu. I want a snapshot from the video.